# How to split array of strings from two sides?

Tags: regex, r

I have an array of strings (n=1000) in this format:

```
   strings<-c("GSM1264936_2202_4866_28368_150cGy-GCSF6-m3_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz",
           "GSM1264937_2202_4866_28369_150cGy-GCSF6-m4_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz",
           "GSM1264938_2202_4866_28370_150cGy-GCSF6-m5_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz")
```

I'm wondering what may be a easy way to get this:

```
strings2<-c(2201_4866_28368_150cGy-GCSF6-m3_Mouse430A+2.CEL,
           2202_4866_28369_150cGy-GCSF6-m4_Mouse430A+2.CEL,
           2203_4866_28370_150cGy-GCSF6-m5_Mouse430A+2.CEL)
```

which means to trim off "GSM1234567" from the front and ".gz" from the end.

Comment: It's not duplicate. Here the start string `2202` is subject to be different. I will make a little bit change of my question.

Comment: oh, my mistake... did not notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a `gsub` solution that matches strings that starts `^` with digits and alphabetical symbols, zero or more times `*`, until a `_` is encountered and (more precisely "or") pieces or strings that have `.gz` at the end `$`.

```
 gsub("^([[:alnum:]]*_)|(\\.gz)$", "", strings)
[1] "2202_4866_28368_150cGy-GCSF6-m3_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
[2] "2202_4866_28369_150cGy-GCSF6-m4_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
[3] "2202_4866_28370_150cGy-GCSF6-m5_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
```

#### Edit

I forget to escape the second point.

Answer (score 1):

```
strings <- c("GSM1264936_2202_4866_28368_150cGy-GCSF6-m3_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz", "GSM1264937_2202_4866_28369_150cGy-GCSF6-m4_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz", "GSM1264938_2202_4866_28370_150cGy-GCSF6-m5_Mouse430A+2.CEL.gz")
strings2 <- lapply(strings, function (x) substr(x, 12, 58))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `sub`:

```
sub('[^_]+_(.*)\\.gz', '\\1', strings)
# [1] "2202_4866_28368_150cGy-GCSF6-m3_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
# [2] "2202_4866_28369_150cGy-GCSF6-m4_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
# [3] "2202_4866_28370_150cGy-GCSF6-m5_Mouse430A+2.CEL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 gsub('^[^_]+_|\\.[^.]*$','',strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest doing this in two steps. The other solutions work but are completely unreadable: they don’t express the *intent* of your code. Here it is, clearly expressed:

```
trimmed_prefix = sub('^GSM\\d+_', '', strings)
strings2 = sub('\\.gz$', '', trimmed_prefix)
```

But admittedly this *can* be expressed in one step, and wouldn’t look too badly, as follows:

```
strings2 = sub('^GSM\\d+_(.*)\\.gz$', '\\1', strings)
```

In general, think carefully about the patterns you actually want to match: your question says to match the prefix “GSM1234567” but your example contradicts that. I’d generally choose a pattern that’s *as specific as possible* to avoid accidentally matching faulty input.

Comment: what for strings that start with `GSM1264937_`  and `...8` ?

Comment: @SabDeM Hm. I see. OP’s question was inaccurate then. I’ll amend my answer.